# Why JSONParser doesn't remove the " from keys and values?

Tags: gwt, json

I have the following JSON-String:

```
{"locale":"de","strings":[{"key":"navigation.search","value":"Suchen"}]}
```

I try to parse it this way:

```
// parse the response text into JSON
String json = response.getText();
Window.alert(json);
JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseLenient("{\"locale\":\"de\",\"strings\":[{\"key\":\"navigation.search\",\"value\":\"Suchen\"}]}");
Window.alert(jsonValue.isObject().get("locale").toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isObject().get("strings").isArray();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    Window.alert(jsonArray.get(i).isObject().get("key").isString() + " -> " + jsonArray.get(i).isObject().get("value").isString());
}
```

Why are there quotes in the Window.alert(), I thought, the quotes are essential, for creating JSON.

By the way, the JSON is created with the json.org Java-Classes:

```
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(System.err);
new JSONWriter(w)
     .object()
          .key("locale").value("de").key("strings").array().object().key("key").value("navigation.search").key("value").value("Suchen").endObject().endArray()
     .endObject();
w.flush();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the key is to use the [stringValue](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONString.html#stringValue%28%29) method. Try:

> jsonArray.get(i).isObject().get("value").isString().stringValue()